# Sending unique ID to database from Android phone

Tags: java, android

I am implementing fingerprint using AndroidX biometrics.

But now I want to sent some unique ID/Name to database to put into database timestamp.

But for now I read that I cant access fingerprint in my phone.

Is there any kind of thing that I could sent to database? Unique phone ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AdID

Kotlin example

```
var id = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(this.getApplicationContext()).getId() //kotlin
```

Java Example

```
String id = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(this.getApplicationContext()).getId() //Java
```

Refer this documentation for more details

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#java

Comment: it says
```Cannot resolve method 'getId' in 'ListenableFuture'```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Let me know if this works